# Unusual behavior in testing: node.js/ Mocha

Tags: node.js, express, testing, tdd, mocha.js

I recently jumped into nodeJS and started building a middleware applicaiton using Express & Wagnor

below is my package.JSON

```
{
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "3.8.11",
  "gulp-mocha": "2.0.1",
  "mocha": "2.2.4",
  "superagent": "1.2.0",
  "wagner-core": "0.1.0"
 },
  "dependencies": {
    "underscore": "1.5.2",
  "mongodb": "2.2.10",
  "express": "",
  "http-status": "0.1.8",
  "mongoose":""
 },
 "scripts": {
 "test": "mocha test.js"
 }
 }
```

i am stuck in a very peculiar situation and searched for similar incident reports but could not get any relevant. I am sure i am making a silly mistake and need assistance in identifying it.

Here is the scenario, i have a basic middle-ware setup with 6 endpoints, and i am testing using mocha.

I have a test.js file with 6 tests and problem is that when i run it it passes once and fails another time and then passes again without any intervention to env or code or tests. This makes me very concerned that weather my application will behave similarly in production or it is a tests related issue or a known mocha issue (couldn't find any).

Below is my test file

```
var URL_ROOT = 'http://localhost:3131';
var express = require('express');
var wagner = require('wagner-core');
var assert = require('assert');
var superagent = require('superagent');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//mongoose.set('debug', true);

var PRODUCT_ID = '0000000000000000000001';

describe('Store API', function(){
    var server; 
    var Product;
    var Catagory;
    var User;


    before(function() {
        var app = express();

        // Bootstrap sertver
        models = require('./models')(wagner);
        require('./dependencies')(wagner);
        app.use(require('./api')(wagner));
        wagner.invoke(require('./auth'), {app: app});
        server = app.listen(3131);

        //Make Catagory and Product model available in test
        Catagory = models.Catagory;
        Product = models.Product;
        User = models.User;


        app.use( function(req, res, next) {
          User.findOne({}, function(error, user) {
               console.log('Time:', Date.now());
               assert.ifError(error);
               req.user = user;
               next();
           });  //user.findone
       }); //app.use
    }); //before

    after(function(){
        //Shut the server
        server.close();
    }); //after

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        //Make sure Catagories are empty before each test
        Catagory.remove({}, function(error) {
            assert.ifError(error);
            Product.remove({}, function(error) {
                assert.ifError(error);
                User.remove({}, function(error) {
                    assert.ifError(error);
                    //Create Products, Catagories and Users
                    var catagories = [
                        { _id: 'Electronics'},
                        { _id: 'Phones', parent: 'Electronics'},
                        { _id: 'Laptop', parent: 'Electronics'},
                        { _id: 'Meat'}
                    ];

                    // create product data
                    var products = [
                        {
                            _id: '00000000000001',
                            name: 'LG G4',
                            catagory: { _id: 'Phones', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Phones']},
                            price: {
                                amount: 300,
                                currency: 'USD'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            _id: '00000000000002',
                            name: 'Asus Zenbook Prime',
                            catagory: { _id: 'Laptop', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Laptop']},
                            price: {
                                amount: 2000,
                                currency: 'USD'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            _id: '00000000000003',
                            name: 'MeatOne Goasht Wala',
                            catagory: {_id: 'Meat', ancestors: ['Meat']},
                            price: {
                                amount: 20,
                                currency: 'USD'
                            }
                        }
                    ];

                    var users = [{
                        profile: {
                            username: 'shoaibhb',
                            picture: 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/364903575/ShoaibHayat_Butt.jpg'
                        },
                        data: {
                            oauth: 'invalid',
                            cart: []
                        }
                    }];

                    Catagory.create( catagories, function(error) {
                        assert.ifError(error)
                        Product.create(products, function(error) {
                            assert.ifError(error)
                              User.create(users, function(error) {
                                  assert.ifError(error);
                                  User.findOne({}, function(err, user) {

                                  });
                             });
                        });
                    });
                });
                done();
            });
        });
    });

    it('can load a Catagory by id', function(done) {
        // Create a single Catagory
        // Catagory.create({ _id: 'Electronics' }, function(error, doc) {
        //     assert.ifError(error);
            var url = URL_ROOT + '/catagory/id/Electronics';
            //Make and HTTP request to localhost:3131/catagory/id/Electronics
            superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                assert.ifError(error);
                var result;
                // and make sure we got { _id: 'Electronics'} back
                assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                    result = JSON.parse(res.text);
                });
                assert.ok(result.catagory);
                assert.equal(result.catagory._id, 'Electronics');
                done();
            });
        //});// ends here
    });

    it('can load all Catagories that have a certain parent', function(done) {

        // Create 4 catagories was here earlier, moved to beforeEach()

        //Catagory.create(catagories, function(error, catagories) {
            var url = URL_ROOT + '/catagory/parent/Electronics';
            //make HTTP request to /catagory/parent/Electronics
            superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                assert.ifError(error);
                var result;
                assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                    result = JSON.parse(res.text);
                });
                assert.equal(result.catagories.length, 2);
                // should be in assending order by _id
                assert.equal(result.catagories[0]._id, 'Laptop');
                assert.equal(result.catagories[1]._id, 'Phones');
                done();
            });
        //});// create cat ends here
    });

    it('can load a product by id', function(done) {
        //Create a single product


        var oneProduct = {
                name: 'LG G4',
                _id: PRODUCT_ID,
                catagory: { _id: 'Phones', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Phones']},
                price: {
                    amount: 300,
                    currency: 'USD'
                }
            };

        Product.create(oneProduct, function(error, doc) {
          assert.ifError( error);
            var url = URL_ROOT + '/product/id/' + PRODUCT_ID;
            // Make HTTP request to 
            // localhost:3131/product/id/0000000000000000000001
            superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                assert.ifError(error);
                var result = {};
                //And make sure we got LG G4 back

                assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                    result = JSON.parse(res.text);
                });

                assert.ok(result.product);
                assert.equal(result.product._id, PRODUCT_ID);
                assert.equal(result.product.name, 'LG G4');
                done();
            });     
        });
    });

    it('can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories', function(done) {

        // moved to beforeEach function 

                var url = URL_ROOT + '/product/catagory/Electronics';
                //Make HTTP Request to loca:3131
                superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                    assert.ifError(error);
                    var result;
                    assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                        result = JSON.parse(res.text);                
                    });
                    assert.equal(result.product.length, 2);
                    // should be assending order by name
                    assert.equal(result.product[0].name, 'Asus Zenbook Prime');
                    assert.equal(result.product[1].name, 'LG G4');

                    //Sort by price , assending
                    var url = URL_ROOT + '/product/catagory/Electronics?price=1';
                    superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                        assert.ifError(error);
                        var result;
                        assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                            result = JSON.parse(res.text);
                        });
                        assert.equal(result.product[0].name, 'LG G4');
                        assert.equal(result.product[1].name, 'Asus Zenbook Prime');
                    });
                    //console.log(error);
                    assert.ifError(error);
                    done();
            });
    });


    it('can load user cart', function(done) {
        var url = URL_ROOT + '/me/';
        User.findOne({}, function( error, user) {
            console.log("error %j",error);
            //assert.ifError(error);
            user.data.cart = [{ product: PRODUCT_ID, quantity: 1}];
            console.log(user.data.cart);
            user.save(function(error) {
                assert.ifError(error);
                superagent.get(url, function(error, res) {
                    assert.ifError(error);
                    assert.equal(res.status, 200);
                    var result;
                    assert.doesNotThrow(function() {
                        result = JSON.parse(res.text).user;
                    });
                    assert.equal(result.data.cart.length,1);
                    assert.equal(result.data.cart[0].product.name, 'Asus Zenbook Prime');
                    assert.equal(result.data.cart[0].quantity, 1);

                });
            });
        });
        done();
    });



    it('can save user cart', function(done) {
        var url = URL_ROOT + '/me/cart/';

        superagent.put(url).send({
             data: {
                 cart: [{ product: PRODUCT_ID, quantity: 1}]
             }
         }).end(function(error, res) {
             assert.ifError(error);
             assert.equal(res.status, status.OK);
             User.findOne({}, function(error, user) {
                 assert.ifError(error);
                 assert.equal(user.data.cart.length, 1);
                 assert.equal(user.data.cart[0].product, PRODUCT_ID);
                 assert.equal(user.data.cart[0], quantity, 1);
             });
         });
         done();
    });
    enter code here

});
```

When i run these tests, here is what happens:
a) 6 Tests pass
b) Some test fail
c) there is a blank response

```
D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js

D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (81ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent
    √ can load a product by id
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    1) "before each" hook


  5 passing (752ms)
  1 failing

  1) Store API "before each" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
      at test-6passing.js:243:17
      at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1173:16
      at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16




D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (89ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent (38ms)
    √ can load a product by id
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    1) "before each" hook


  5 passing (922ms)
  1 failing

  1) Store API "before each" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
      at test-6passing.js:243:17
      at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1173:16
      at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16




D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (96ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent
    √ can load a product by id
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    √ can save user cart


  6 passing (852ms)


D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js

D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (80ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent
    √ can load a product by id
    1) can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    2) "before each" hook


  4 passing (862ms)
  2 failing

  1) Store API can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories:

      Uncaught AssertionError: 0 == 2
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +2

      at test-6passing.js:215:28
      at Request.callback (node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:785:12)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules\superagent\lib\node\index.js:
990:12)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:913:12)

  2) Store API "before each" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
      at test-6passing.js:243:17
      at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1173:16
      at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16




D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (86ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent (38ms)
    √ can load a product by id
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    1) "before each" hook


  5 passing (744ms)
  1 failing

  1) Store API "before each" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
      at test-6passing.js:243:17
      at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1173:16
      at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16




D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (97ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent (43ms)
    √ can load a product by id
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    √ can save user cart


  6 passing (785ms)


D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (83ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent
    √ can load a product by id (39ms)
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    1) "before each" hook


  5 passing (797ms)
  1 failing

  1) Store API "before each" hook:
     Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
      at test-6passing.js:243:17
      at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1173:16
      at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16




D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js

D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>mocha test-6passing.js


  Store API
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option auth.j
s:57:39
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUnini
tialized option auth.js:57:39
    √ can load a Catagory by id (93ms)
    √ can load all Catagories that have a certain parent (38ms)
    √ can load a product by id
    √ can load all products in a Catagory with sub-catagories
    √ can load user cart
error null
    √ can save user cart


  6 passing (806ms)


D:\Programs_Insalled\nodejs\finalMEAN\edx\retailStore>
```

So the Question:

1. Is there a mistake i am doing
2. Is my approach incorrect
3. Is there an issue in mocha that i don't know
4. This is how it is

My environment is MongoDB, Node, Express, Windows

**EDIT:** complete code can be found here:

```
https://github.com/shoaibhb/retailStore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This i would not call a solution to problem, but it solved my problem. I changed by `beforeEach()` function to separately handle the create and remove of data before each test ant it stabilized it.

Here is the code to what i did.

```
 beforeEach(function(done) {
    // Make sure categories are empty before each test
    Category.remove({}, function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      Product.remove({}, function(error) {
        assert.ifError(error);
        User.remove({}, function(error) {
          assert.ifError(error);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    var categories = [
      { _id: 'Electronics' },
      { _id: 'Phones', 'parent': 'Electronics' },
      { _id: 'Laptops', 'parent': 'Electronics' },
      { _id: 'Bacon' }
    ];

    var products = [
      {
        name: 'LG G4',
        category: { _id: 'Phones', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Phones'] },
        price: {
          amount: 300,
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      },
      {
        _id: PRODUCT_ID,
        name: 'Asus Zenbook Prime',
        category: { _id: 'Laptops', ancestors: ['Electronics', 'Laptops'] },
        price: {
          amount: 2000,
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Flying Pigs Farm Pasture Raised Pork Bacon',
        category: { _id: 'Bacon', ancestors: ['Bacon'] },
        price: {
          amount: 20,
          currency: 'USD'
        }
      }
    ];

    var users = [{
      profile: {
        username: 'vkarpov15',
        picture: 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/550304223036854272/Wwmwuh2t.png'
      },
      data: {
        oauth: 'invalid',
        cart: []
      }
    }];

    Category.create(categories, function(error) {
      assert.ifError(error);
      Product.create(products, function(error) {
        assert.ifError(error);
        User.create(users, function(error) {
          assert.ifError(error);
          done();
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So, there really isn't enough information here, but I can tell you what to look for. Let's start with the error you're getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
  at test-6passing.js:243:17
  at node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1173:16
  at node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
```

So, the second line tells us that the error was thrown in test-6passing.js, at line 243, column 17. So, unfortunately, SO doesn't show line numbers, so I don't know exactly where that is, but you can find that line in your text editor and that will tell you exactly which function is executing when the error occurs.

The first line tells us that you're trying to read the 'data' property of an object, but that object is `null`. Let's say that the function on line 243, at column 17 is `Catagory.remove`-- we can look at that function to know exactly what object was `null` in your test. Then, you'd have to look at *why* it was `null`.

There are countless possible reasons for this. Perhaps you misspelled the object name in the `Catagory.remove` function? Perhaps the information isn't populated yet--javascript is an asynchronous language, which is difficult for many people coming from other programming languages to get used to.

If that doesn't help, try updating your post with the code where the models and their methods/functions are defined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your tests are not leaving the database in the same state every time.  The error is here:

```
it('can load user cart', function(done) {
    var url = URL_ROOT + '/me/';
    User.findOne({}, function( error, user) {
        console.log("error %j",error);
        //assert.ifError(error);
        user.data.cart = [{ product: PRODUCT_ID, quantity: 1}];
```

where `user` is null.  Perhaps some test is deleting a user and another is adding it?

Comment: as much as i understand, `beforeEach()` function does it in sequence, user must be created for each test. and if it is not created for any reason, it should assert an error. which is not the case.